# Php Storm remote files editing

Tags: phpstorm

I am new to PhpStorm. I want to edit files on remote host **without mapping** (like in PhpDesigner). I configured server,  opened in on Remote Host window and I watch all files, but when I click on file it is not open in editor. How to do this?

Comment: Currently there's no official way to edit remote files without local copy. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310339/using-remote-server-in-phpstorm#comment19882648_14310339) and [this](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5287181;jsessionid=6FDDFB37B1A014A85C8AD46FD2A4DCDB#5287181).

Comment: A ticket to watch: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1398

Answer (score 3):

In new EAP version of PHPStorm You can edit remote file. http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/04/remote-edit-in-phpstorm-9-eap/

Answer (score 2):

You can only edit local files. This is a lacking in IntelliJ platform IDEs. Sorry for this. You can take a look at [this ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1398), or make one for yourself as a feature request.